# API Only User Unable to Use SAML Assertion Flow Single Sign-On

Tags: api, soap-api, single-sign-on, saml

I'm having an issue using the SAML Assertion Flow with API Only users (See SAML Assertion Flow https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm&language=en_US )

I am able to get into the APIs, and my SAML assertions are correct - I've used the same process w/ my own user account and been able to use SSO w/o issue.

Is there any way to get this to work for API only users?

**More Info:**

- Identity Provider - ADFS w/ Rollup 3
- I generate the SAML assertion using the IDP initiated sign-on
  endpoint on ADFS.  It uses the same profile that is used for
  web-based SSO, but the SAML assertion is posted to the
  https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?so=00D000000000
  endpoint (not the actual endpoint, mind you)
- I get a json response.

Thanks in advance

NOTE: I've crossed-listed this on the SF site, for anyone suffering from deja-vu :)  [SF Post Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000kB3IIAU)